# How could I Indicate the entry section and exit section in the TestandSet()

Tags: critical-section

`TestandSet()` is an atomic operation as follows:

```
boolean TestandSet(boolean *target)
{ 
    boolean prev = *target;
    *target = true; // always set true
    return prev; // return previous value
}
```

`TestandSet()` can be applied to achieve mutual exclusion as follows:

```
do {
 while (TestandSet(&lock))
   ; /* loop and wait */
   // critical section
   lock = false;
    // remainder section
}
```

Q1: How could I Indicate the entry section and exit section in the above code

Q2 The question is Assume there are two processes P1 and P2 executing the above code and P1 starts slightly ahead of P2. Assume lock is initilized as false. Give a trace of excution of P1 and P2, according to the following table.

[The following table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9PiR.png)